# Simulate typing and pressing a key combination in Word on opening document

Tags: vba, ms-word

As soon as my Word document is opened, I want to simulate typing "abcd" followed by ALT+J.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside **[`ThisDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa189914%28v=office.10%29.aspx)** module.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Selection.TypeText ("abcd")
    SendKeys "%{K}"
End Sub
```

**Reference: [`SendKeys()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943%28v=office.10%29.aspx)**

Comment: When I run this in VBA code editor, Alt+K is executed in the editor and not in the Word document. But I guess that won't be a problem when the code is executed in the Word document, without the VBA editor?

Comment: @Korneel Yes. The window on top recieves the key-input.